# What does the Maven well known qualifier of sp stand for?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have read several good articles on the Maven versioning with well known qualifiers.  However, I found it interesting that after the so called 'final' release which is an empty qualifier, ga, or final I can't find any article that describes how the sp qualifier might be used. Evidently it compares greater than the final qualifier, but I've no idea of the letters stand for something in particular or if there is some popular software release convention that uses that qualifier.  rc would typically mean release candidate, so I would think that sp would have some kind of meaning and that the letters were chosen in accordance with some kind of pattern.

Here is one of the articles I've already read, and I see no info that would give me a hint as to what sp means or how it might be used.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this stands for "service pack" and therefore describes corrections/additions after the final release.